# How (much) 'private' our C# class members are?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, access-modifiers

We can use reflection to get or set value of any `private` member in C# class. (using `BindingFlags.NonPublic` etc.)

If this is the case, how come `private` member is really private? How can we be assured that the things which are purposely stored in the `private` fields remain private in true sense?

Comment: You can't really prevent this - reflection is a backdoor into the implementation of your class.

Comment: In reality, you can't; Making an implementation `private` `internal`, etc is about specifying intent in the design and how components are intended to be used.

Comment: This question was asked a number of times. This one has great answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2084353/694852. And this one was havily upvoted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16942114/694852.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Access modifiers are there to provide encapsulation for object orientated programming, not for runtime security.

If you need security, you will need to use higher level features.

- [Obfuscate your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478230/how-can-i-protect-my-net-assemblies-from-decompilation)
- [Limit who can call your methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806842/secure-c-sharp-assemblies-from-unauthorized-callers)